# How Get type of format QR Code in zxing?

Tags: android, zxing

How get type of format QR Code zxing ? 
because with the Format QR Code, there are different types: (sms, url, contact, email ...). 
IntentResult.java not make that Format of a bar code

Comment: @Lucifer is right...accept some answers, and people may be more likely to help. If you asked a question, if you hover your cursor just below where you vote up/down, you will get an option to select the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Find the class `ResultParser` in `core/`. It parses the raw contents into something more structured. You can reuse this.

Answer (score 0):

it returns to you the raw string, if you are interested in the format I imagine you'd have to parse it yourself to find it.